# how to add values dynamically in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to add dynamically values of element of JSON in AngularJS. Below is my HTML tag where I want to display it:

```
<tr>  
  <th class="right"> Ending Value<span class="subVal">:</span></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="right">$21,50,868.06</td>
</tr>
```

Now for this ending value, I want that it should be the sum of `retailAcctTotalBalance` elements of below json :

```
"acconnts": [{
    "userName": null,
    "retailAcctNumber": "574436368",
    "retailAcctTotalBalance": 0.0
}, {
    "userName": null,
    "retailAcctNumber": "101215858",
    "retailAcctTotalBalance": 2118639.38
}, {
    "userName": null,
    "retailAcctNumber": "101900352",
    "retailAcctTotalBalance": 32228.68
}, {
    "userName": null,
    "retailAcctNumber": "574435165",
    "retailAcctTotalBalance": 0.0
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to go:

In your html file, you can do:

```
<td class="right">{{ sum }} </td>
```

And, in your controller:

```
$scope.sum = 0;
$scope.accounts = { /* your json data */ };
angular.forEach($scope.accounts, function(acc, index) {
    $scope.sum += acc.retailAcctTotalBalance;
});
```

Comment: good for initial controller load, won't update if/when data changes though

Answer (score 0):

One approach, add a function in scope that outputs what you want from your model

```
$scope.total=function(){
   var total=0;
   angular.forEach($scope.accounts, function(account) {
      total += acc.retailAcctTotalBalance;
    });
    return total;
});
```

In Markup:

```
<td class="right">{{ total() }} </td>
```

Now whenever an update is made to the data, angular watchers will run a digest cycle, on each digest cycle it will evaluate the scope function found in the markup

Another way is to watch the data and update a variable whenever it changes

```
$scope.total=0;
$scope.accounts={ /* data*/}

$scopw.$watch('accounts',function(newVal,oldVal){
   if(newVal != undefined)
   $scope.total = getTotal();
})

function getTotal(){
   var total=0;
   angular.forEach($scope.accounts, function(account) {
      total += acc.retailAcctTotalBalance;
    });
    return total;
});
```

In Markup:

```
<td class="right">{{ total }} </td>
```